# Visual Feedback for custom button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, radial-gradients

I have a custom button in my main window that I would like to have the ability to provide some visual feedback to the user when it is clicked, and when the mouse hovers over it. I use the `RadialGrandientBrush` to color my button. I would like to continue using it in these events, but I don't know how to implement it inside a `trigger`.

Here is my current code:

```
   <Button Width="100"
        Height="100" Click="Button_Click_1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                         StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                          Color="White" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="LightSkyBlue" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="LightSkyBlue" />
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!--- THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO USE THE RADIALGRADIENTBRUSH AGAIN -->
                        <Setter ........ />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

</Window>
```

How do I use a brush, such as `RadialGradientBrush` as a setter, inside a trigger?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can name your `Ellipse` in the control template using `x:Name` and access it by using `TargetName` property on the `Setter` in the triggers section.

Sample code is below:

```
<Button Width="100"
        Height="100" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" x:Name="ellipse"
                         StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                          Color="White" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="LightSkyBlue" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="LightSkyBlue" />
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Fill">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                          Color="White" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="LightGreen" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="Green" />
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Ideally, you should use `VisualStateManager` to achieve this.

Refer to this [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903963%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) about Customizing the Appearance of a Button by Using a ControlTemplate and VisualStateManager